# Why the value of sum is not printing in the excel cell when the range is properly defined in VBA?

Tags: excel, sum, vba

I have written the following code for the fourth worksheet where the number of rows and columns can increase based on the table dimension created in worksheet 1. Here's the code:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
 Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Dim sh4 As Worksheet
 Set sh4 = Worksheets("Sheet 4")
Dim operations As Integer
 operations = sh1.Range("D4").Value
Dim contaminants As Integer
 contaminants = sh1.Range("D6").Value
Dim firstRow As Integer
 firstRow = sh4.Range("B10").Row
Dim operation As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
 lastRow = firstRow + operations*contaminants - contaminants - operation
Dim b As Integer
 b = 0
Dim c As Integer
 c = 0

  While c <= contaminants - 2
   If sh4.Cells(10+b,3+c) = "Count" Then
    sh4.Cells(10+b,3+c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sh4.Range(sh4.Cells(firstRow, (3+c)), sh4.Cells(lastRow, (3+c))))
   Else
    b = b + 1
   End If
   c = c + 1
  Wend
```

The code will do just the part of introducing the sum of defined range whenever it founds in column C the word "Count". Then it prints the value into column D, and advance into column E and so on until reaching contaminants - 2. Basically, I just want to print the result into D16 and E16 and I am not understanding what's wrong with: sh4.Cells(10+b,3+c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sh4.Range(sh4.Cells(firstRow, (3+c)), sh4.Cells(lastRow, (3+c))))

```
    C     D     E  
10  1     0     -
11  2     -     1
12  3     1     -
13  4     -     1
14  5     1     -
15  6     -     1
16 Count  2     3
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Tangential: `Dim b As Integer` ==> `Dim b As Long` (etc. for other ones). Given that modern versions of Excel run on 32 or 64 bit machines and have over a million rows, using `Integer` is both pointless and potentially harmful. You are just setting yourself up for overflow errors if and when your data grows past a certain point.

Comment: Is it right that you're incrementing `c` every time in your While-Wend loop?

Comment: @SJR if he didn't increment c then it would overflow as c would never pass the exit condition.

Comment: @Zerk - I wondered if c should be incremented within the If, like b. That said, not sure I follow exactly what the OP is doing.

Comment: @SJR - Valid point, based on the existing logic if it doesn't find the count row on its first try it moves onto the next column, once it has found the row it would apply it consistently. I'm not sure why it's not hunting for the count row initially and setting that into a variable then simply iterating the columns.

Comment: Thank you John. But is it the reason why it doesn't print the value in excel cell?

SJR, I want that after the value is printed in a cell it advance in column.

Comment: @SJR, yes I could increment c within the If like b. However, I will need a condition to stop applying the If which I found that could be done by simply iterating the columns. My question is that the Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum is not working and I don't understand why. At least, it must print the value of 2 in cell D16.

Comment: @vbalearner It has nothing to do with the problem, which is why I described it as tangential.

Comment: If "Count" is always in column C as soon as `c` is incremented above zero that text will never be found. What is the value of `lastrow`? Also you are putting the formula in the same cell as the on in which "Count" is found.

Comment: @SJR thanks. Well seen. I am going to see how to change the code. Will give news as soon as i get it fixed. The firstrow and lastrow is to define the row range

Comment: @SJR, is this range not defined properly? I don't see any reason not to work. sh4.Range(sh4.Cells(firstRow, (3 + c)), sh4.Cells(lastRow, (3 + c))

Comment: See my previous comment. You could be placing the formula in the range over which it is calculating. What exactly is the problem here - is the code erroring, or doing nothing or not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: Its doing nothing. Does not print the value in excel cell.

Comment: I can only assume it goes through the whole loop without the condition ever being satisfied.

Comment: @SJR can you explain then why the code posted by Zerk is working but does not print the value on the worksheet cell? I can't find any reason not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions made are explained, integers replaced with longs, "Count" row number set in a variable, loop replaced with a for loop.

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
 Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Dim sh4 As Worksheet
 Set sh4 = Worksheets("Sheet 4")
Dim operations As Long
 operations = sh1.Range("D4").Value
Dim contaminants As Long
 contaminants = sh1.Range("D6").Value
Dim firstRow As Long
 firstRow = sh4.Range("B10").Row
Dim operation As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
 lastRow = firstRow + operations * contaminants - contaminants - operation
Dim CountRow As Long
Dim lng As Long
'Assuming column 3 onwards has "count" and it always exists on the same row
CountRow = Application.Match("Count", sh4.Columns(3), 0)

'Start at column 4, assuming we don't want to overwrite "Count" in column C
For lng = 4 To contaminants - 2
    sh4.Cells(CountRow, lng) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sh4.Range(sh4.Cells(firstRow, lng), sh4.Cells(lastRow, lng)))
Next lng
```